# How to remove extra spaces in Flutter button bar?

Tags: flutter

I've been coding this button bar in flutter and It always keeps extra space between two buttons. Tried padding, TapTargetSize but nothing work. Any ideas why?

Here's my code

```
 Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                      onPressed: () {/*Do Something*/},
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                      child: new Icon(
                        Icons.file_upload,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 15.0,
                      ),
                      shape: new CircleBorder(),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    ),
                    FlatButton();
                    FlatButton();
                    FlatButton();

                  ],
                )
```

And heres what this looks like.

[image]

**Had to remove the code for other 3 buttons because most of this question is code. Other 3 buttons are similar to the first one

Comment: Hi Suvin, is your doubt answered or do you need more information?

Comment: Problem solved Matt! Thanks!

Comment: I used InkWell, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394457/flutter-buttonrow-padding

Answer (score 4):

You are using [`FlatButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html) which uses a minimum size of 88.0 by 36.0 as noted in the documentation.

Your options are to:

- Override this with the ButtonTheme
- Use [`IconButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) instead as that's how you seem to be using the button anyway
- Wrap each of your buttons in a `SizedBox` as below:

---

```
SizedBox(
 width: 40,
 child: FlatButton(),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Button in Expanded Widget:

```
Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    onPressed: () {/*Do Something*/},
    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.file_upload,
      color: Colors.black,
      size: 15.0,
    ),
    shape: new CircleBorder(),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  ),
),
```